# How to get Memory Usage from Windows Server 2012 R2 in OpenStack

Tags: monitoring, openstack, windows-server, ceilometer

I have a *Rocky OpenStack cluster* that I want to monitor the memory usage of instances.

monitoring Linux instances is OK but Windows Server instances do not provide any data for memory usage.

I've searched a lot, and I've installed the *balloon* driver on Windows instances but it did not work for me. All components are updated to the latest version.

So, how can I get memory usage data from them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be Install the **Virtio Balloon** driver AND the **Balloon service** in the guest:

1-Open Device Manager and see if there is an unknown PCI device. If so, right click it and install the driver manually from D:\Balloon\2K16\amd64 (or 2k12, 2k8, etc)

2-Now copy the entire amd64 folder into C:\Program Files\  and rename it "Balloon". So, now you have the amd64 folder from the disc copied as C:\Program Files\Balloon

3-Open an Administrative Command Prompt and cd to C:\Program Files\Balloon

4-Run this command:

```
BLNSVR.exe -i
```